# How could we caluculate the amount of heat transferred through convection when a fluid flows over a curved surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, convection, thermal-conduction

In the case of convection heat transfer during fluid flow over a flat plate , we deduce the governing equations based on conservation of mass , momentum and energy, using this equations we find the boundary layer thickness and going forward with this , heat transferred could be evaluated. 1)Is it possible for us to take the same approach for curved surfaces ?
2)As the curvature is present do we have a varying value of boundary layer thickness?
3)help me out showing an approach to solve curved surface heat transfer and also the assumptions to be taken .

Comment: See Example 12.4-3 in Chapter 12 of Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Comment: How curved is the surface relative to the thickness of the boundary layer?